$\beta^-$ decay of $^{247}\rm{Cm}$ to excited states of $^{247}\rm{Bk}$
The nuclide $^{247}\rm{Cm}$ is only known to be an alpha emitter with a half life of $1.56\times 10^7$ years. In theory, it is also capable of $\beta^-$ decay to $^{247}\rm{Bk}$ with a $Q$ value of $43.28\,\rm{keV}$, but it seems that the decay mode is hindered because this is a $9/2^-\to 3/2^-$ transition.
On the other hand, $^{247}\rm{Bk}$ has a $5/2^-$ state at $29.88\,\rm{keV}$ and a $7/2^-$ state at $40.81\,\rm{keV}$ (see here), so it is still possible that $^{247}\rm{Cm}$ can undergo a $9/2^-\to 5/2^-$ transition ($\Delta J^{\Delta\pi}=2^-$) with a $Q$ value of $13.40\,\rm{keV}$, or a $9/2^-\to 7/2^+$ transition  ($\Delta J^{\Delta\pi}=1^-$) with a $Q$ value of $2.47\,\rm{keV}$. The former process is $2$ forbidden non-unique with a relatively small $Q$ value, so I wouldn't expect it to happen easily. What about the $9/2^-\to 7/2^+$ transition, which is only $1$ forbidden non-unique?
I know that the $Q$ value is very low, but it is known that $^{157}\rm{Tb}$ ($J^\pi = 3/2^+$) can undergo EC decay to the $5/2^-$ state of $^{157}\rm{Gd}$ (see here). This process also has $\Delta J^{\Delta\pi}=1^-$ like the potential $9/2^-\to 7/2^+$ transition of $^{247}\rm{Cm}$, and its $Q$ value is as low as $5.5\,\rm{keV}$, yet its half-life is only about $6.5\times 10^4$ years. As another example, the EC process $^{243}\rm{Cm}\to{}^{243}\rm{Am}$ ($5/2^+\to 5/2^-$) also has a $Q$ value of only $7.48\,\rm{keV}$. The decay is also $1$ forbidden non-unique, yet the half-life is only about $10^4$ years. What makes $^{247}\rm{Cm}$ particular (i.e., with such $\beta$-stability)?

Well, after finding no reasonable explantion given the striking example of $^{157}\mathrm{Tb}$, I have no choice but to believe that the $9/2^-\to 7/2^+$ transition is actually energetically disallowed. Looking at NUBASE2020, the mass excesses of $^{247}\mathrm{Cm}$ and $^{247}\mathrm{Bk}$ are respectively $65533\pm 4,\mathrm{keV}$ and $65490\pm 5,\mathrm{keV}$, so the decay energy has an error margin of $9,\mathrm{keV}$. It is thus very likely that the energy is actually negative.
